# Can we create one datafile for two tablespaces in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

there is no possibility to store one data files in to two table space.but when creating IOT in oracle we are giving over flow property to another table space!
usually data file contains tables even IOT see this image Click for concept [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm)!so how can point out two tablespace for pointing one table(IOT).
let is consider the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE admin_docindex(
        token char(20), 
        doc_id NUMBER,
        token_frequency NUMBER,
        token_offsets VARCHAR2(2000),
        CONSTRAINT pk_admin_docindex PRIMARY KEY (token, doc_id))
    ORGANIZATION INDEX 
    TABLESPACE admin_tbs
    PCTTHRESHOLD 20
    OVERFLOW TABLESPACE admin_tbs2;
```

Comment: not sure that I understand what your question really is. If you are asking how a table has two tablespaces associated with it, then its possible, as a tablespace is assigned to a segment level (and the overflow segment is therefore able to be stored in a different tablespace to the main IOT). It's just like with a partitioned table; each partition of that table could be in its own tablespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One [segment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/glossary.htm#CNCPT2105) in Oracle will be stored in exactly one tablespace.  But one object may be comprised of many different segments.  For example, if you have a partitioned table, each partition is a separate segment each of which may be stored in a different tablespace.  Each `LOB` in a table is a separate segment that can potentially be stored in a different tablespace.  And, in your case, the row overflow area is a separate segment from the segment storing the main table segment.

The various scenarios where a [table can comprise multiple segments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34583/can-a-table-belong-to-multiple-tablespaces/34584#34584) was discussed over on the DBA stack yesterday.

Comment: how one object comprise many segments!,actually that object is already stored in  a particular table space right!then?

Comment: @Thiyagu - I'm not sure I understand the comment.  I've already pointed out a number of situations where one object is comprised of multiple segments.  Each segment is potentially stored in a different tablespace.